# Why every change in Asus UX50v causes screen resolution get lost?

Tags: windows-7, display

Why every change in Asus UX50v causes screen resolution get lost?

Installing a new application, connecting to another wireless network, change some settings, ... causes this problem. For example after installing an application, UX50v needs to restart. And when it got restarted, resolution would be set to 640x480(or 600x800) and Hibernate and Sleep options are disappeared from shutdown menu!

Comment: Did the notebook come with Windows 7 pre-installed, or did you install it yourself? It sounds like some of your drivers are missing/broken (the graphics and power ones in particular). Perhaps check the ASUS support site to see if there are any updated ones?

Comment: Windows 7 (Home Premium) was pre-installed. That's the sad part. ASUS did not provided any updates (yet) and I can not update my windows too. Because it crashes.

Comment: 1) Super User is not your soapbox. There is no need to use strong language here. 2) If you have other problems, ask them separately, in different questions.

Comment: @Hello71 I did not notice my strong language (unless you are an ASUS employee; and now I am). And OK; I will delete this post after you have read this comment (This comment has a strong language; but my post does not; I am not a native english and I do not apologize unless you show me my strong points. How embarrassing...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas to try:

1. Update video driver from the manufacturer's website
2. Reboot into Safe mode, uninstall video driver, reboot, reinstall video driver
3. Check the integrity of Windows system files : [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html)
4. Run anti-virus scans, including [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/anti-virus/malwarebytes-anti-malware?1) and [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/), as well as online scans such as [ESET](http://www.eset.com/online-scanner) and [TrendMicro](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/).

**EDIT**

As in a comment you have said that this problem happens even after you reinstall Windows 7, there is always the chance that this is a problem with the on-board video adapter. If the Asus is still under warranty, it might be worthwhile to have this checked.

Comment: I have found and downloaded proper video card driver but it says it can not find a compatible hardware on the machine.

Comment: Then it is not the right driver. What is the name of your video adapter?

Comment: It's NVIDIA GeForce G105M.

Comment: I suggest to use Internet Explorer to go on the Nvidia [Support site](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and use Option 2 to automatically detect the right graphical driver. Only if this doesn't work for some reason, [this one](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-win7-winvista-266.58-whql-driver.html) seems to be your driver.

Comment: Now I have problems with JAVA! I think I should tolerate the situation until I have more time for that. This is not my primary laptop. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your driver, that computer seem to have NVIDIA® GeForce® G 105M, go to 
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us
and select your graphic card and OS, then download the correct drivers, lets see if that fixes the resolution issue.
In a side line, why dont you try reinstalling Win7? it seems like you have several issues.

I know this is not exactly the answer to your problem, but to be honest i dont see another solution.
Sorry to say this, but if the UX50V crashes when updating windows ill say go ask for your warranty.

Comment: Thank you @Gonzalo Peci for replay; I have reinstalled Win 7 from recovery DVDs, but no luck. I will try what you've said; I hope it will solve my problem.